# ContourPlot does not show correct ratio of two functions

Tags: plotting

I am using `ContourPlot` to compare the norm of the two vector fields,  $||\boldsymbol{f}||/||\boldsymbol{g}||$, which should be contour on $(x,y)$ plane.

Consider the following PDEs about $u(x,y,t)$ and $v(x,y,t)$,

```
L = 4;
solu = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y], t, t] == 
D[u[t, x, y], x, x] + D[u[t, x, y], y, y] + Sin[u[t, x, y]], 
u[t, -L, y] == u[t, L, y], u[t, x, -L] == u[t, x, L], u[0, x, y] == Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], 
Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][0, x, y] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 4}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}]

solv = NDSolveValue[{D[v[t, x, y], t, t] == 
D[v[t, x, y], x, x] + D[v[t, x, y], y, y]/2 + (1 - v[t, x, y]^2) (1 + 2 v[t, x, y]), 
v[0, x, y] == E^-(x^2 + y^2), v[t, -L, y] == v[t, L, y], 
v[t, x, -L] == v[t, x, L], Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][0, x, y] == 0}, 
v, {t, 0, 4}, {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}]
```

and these two vector fields

```
f[x_, y_, t_] = solu[t, x, y]*Grad[solv[t, x, y], {x, y}] + Grad[solu[t, x, y], {x, y}];

g[x_, y_, t_] = Grad[solu[t, x, y], {x, y}]*solu[t, x, y];
```

I can plot the respective contours with

```
{ContourPlot[Norm[f[x, y, 1]], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 10, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All], FrameLabel -> {x, y}],
ContourPlot[Norm[g[x, y, 1]], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 10, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All], FrameLabel -> {x, y}]}
```

[image]

**But if I plot their ratio, i.e. the ratio of the norms of the two vector fields, `ContourPlot` produces a strange result, which looks not correct.**

```
ContourPlot[Norm[f[x, y, 1]]/Norm[g[x, y, 1]], {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, PlotRange -> All,
ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 10, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, All], FrameLabel -> {x,y}]
```

[image]

A quick check:

```
Norm[f[1.6, 0.5, 1]]/Norm[g[1.6, 0.5, 1]]
(*4.72938*)
```

This is not consistent with the last contour plot. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe plot the contours of `Log[ Norm[ f[x, y, 1] ] / Norm[ g[x, y, 1] ] ]` and use `Log[ Norm[ f[1.6, 0.5, 1] ] / Norm[ g[1.6, 0.5, 1] ] ]` for the sanity check.

Comment: @LouisB thank you, sir. It works, however, how can I convert the legends to the actual values instead of their logarithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contour plot is actually showing the ratio correctly, but the scale is inappropriate.  Here are three methods that can be used to improve the visualization.

**Method 1: Logarithmic Scale**

We can change to a logarithmic scale with the `ScalingFunctions` option like this

```
ContourPlot[Norm[f[x, y, 1]]/Norm[g[x, y, 1]],
 {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log10",
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"],
 FrameLabel -> {x, y},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]
The advantage of Method 1 is that it is easy to apply.

**Method 2: Legend Modifications**

The legend text from Method 1 can be modified with a simple hack, if desired.  First, we define rules to replace the existing legend text.  Then we apply those rules in the `LegendFunction` option to the `BarLegend` function, like this

```
legendTextRules = {
   Text[100000, q___] :> Text[Superscript[10, 5], q],
   Text[10000, q___] :> Text[Superscript[10, 4], q],
   Text[1000, q___] :> Text[Superscript[10, 3], q]};

ContourPlot[Norm[f[x, y, 1]]/Norm[g[x, y, 1]],
 {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log10",
 ColorFunction -> ColorData["Rainbow"],
 FrameLabel -> {x, y},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic,
   LegendFunction -> ((# /. legendTextRules) &)],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The advantage of Method 2 is that legend text looks better.

**Method 3: User-Defined Contours**

We can also define the contours and `ColorFunction` to be used.  This method allows us to add more detail in areas of interest.  First, we define 2 parameters for our color function.  These parameters are the base 10 logs of the minimum and maximum contours, roughly.  Next we defined the list of contours.  Finally, we plot the function with a logarithmic color functions, like this

```
{minLog10, maxLog10} = {-1, 6};
contours = {1/2, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 100, 500, 
             1000, 5000, 10^6};

ContourPlot[Norm[f[x, y, 1]]/Norm[g[x, y, 1]],
 {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L},
 Contours -> contours,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData[
      "Rainbow"][(Log10[#] - minLog10)/
          (maxLog10 - minLog10)] &),
 FrameLabel -> {x, y},
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The advantage of Method 3 is more contours in the lower left corner of the plot.

Comment: thanks. Plotting `Log[10, Norm[f[x, y, 1]]/Norm[g[x, y, 1]]]` gives the same result, except that its legend labels are the log of base 10, for the actual values on the legend instead of their logarithm, we should use `ScalingFunctions -> "Log10"`, right?

Comment: @user55777  In this case `ScalingFunctions -> "Log10"` is preferred over just taking the log of the function.  I take the log first for a quick look at the results to see if that's the right thing to do.  If it works out and I want a plot with a nice legend, then I will switch to `ScalingFunctions`.

Comment: @user55777  BTW, if I was making a `ContourPlot` I would also look at `Plot3D[Log10[Norm[f[x, y, 1]]/Norm[g[x, y, 1]]],
 {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]` as a sanity check and for guidance on what else I need to look at.